# Gradle for Android doesn't build with external library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, gradlew

When I add ANY library in `app/build.gradle` to `dependecies` block I get the folowing error:

```
:app:preDexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Without or with empty

```
dependencies {
}
```

my project builds and runs.

My `gradle.properties` looks like:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `android` closure:

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```